# Mother Base/FOB: Can I climb onto a pipe from the top?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm not getting the action button prompt to climb onto this pipe from any angle. Should it be possible? Am I just doing it wrong?

[image: Example pipe on Mother Base]

Comment: This is fairly off-topic, but pipes *suck*. They make you completely defenseless, extremely slow, and FOB missions are not forgiving. I would avoid them if patrol patterns allow for it. It's very easy to get spotted by some guard on a catwalk behind you while you're climbing one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stand on top of the boxy thing, very close to the edge. The prompt should come up.

Comment: I've since checked others, and it must just be that particular pipe, on the quarantine platform, that doesn't let you climb down. Weird.